# How to create anonymous function in view for getting data?

Tags: php, yii2

I use httpclient to save logs of the project

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-logging.md

Log file creates in folder which is property for

```
'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/http-request.log'
```

I want to make the path dynamic, depending on provider I use. 
F.e. I wait for '@runtime/logs/provider1/http-request.log' or '@runtime/logs/provider2/http-request.log' depending on the provider which logs I want to save.
The question is how to declare anonymous function in attribute logFile to get data from another class?

Comment: You may rewrite the targets class you are using. Then you could change the `logFile` property in the `init` function.

Comment: @paul Class to extend has too many private functions. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/blob/master/CurlTransport.php

Comment: As @scaisEdge answered, his way is a better than rewriting targets class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component config  in confin/main.php is a tyhe defaut config for your needs but you could access to the log componet dinamycally  using  eg:

```
Yii::$app->log->targets['logFile'] = '@runtime/logs/http-request.log';
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great hint. But I do not quite understand how the log->targets communicates with logFile.

Comment: In he component log you set the file you want use for log  ... for undertstand how log work you can see  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html